# Any help is much appreciated. While installing Hyperledger composer getting the below error:

Tags: npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

ERROR RECEIVED BELOW:
npm install -g composer-cli@0.20

npm ERR! 3 errors generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/api/src/node_report.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

Answer (score 0):

Do not use composer. It's deprecated long time back.